# <AppleWebKit Browser> Setting of data attribute in object tag does not load the resource

Tags: javascript, html, safari, webkit

In AppleWebKit based browsers it is observed that changing the data attribute of HTMLObjectElement ( object tag ) does not cause a HTTP request to be sent out to the url and load the resource. 
This works perfectly well in FireFox and Chrome but not in Safari and other AppleWebKit browsers
Following is my code. Please suggest a solution how can I dynamically set the data in object tag

```
   <html>
     <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
              c= document.getElementById('test');
              c.setAttributeNS(null,'data','http://myserver.com/SVG/MyImage.svg');
            }
         </script>
     </head>
     <body>
          <object id="test" data="" type="image/svg+xml" width="320" height="240" />
     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What happens if you just set `c.data` to that string directly, without using "setAttributeNS()"?

Comment: does `setAttribute('data','<url');` work ?

Comment: Raks (or anyone), did you find a resolution to this problem. We have the same issue 8 years later! We find object tags which are dynamically loaded similar to the above won't consistently load with Safari / IoS Chrome (which is really webkit). Chrome on Windows or IoS will load the above code flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

attributes are a nightmare cross-browser, see here-> http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#attributes

jQuery implements it will though cross browser -> http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Even with jquery it does not work for Safari but works for Chrome and FireFox